# What is spec/selector label in an Istio Gateway configuration?

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I am new to Istio Gateway and my goal is to create a Ingress Gateway for a service deployed on K8s.

I am a bit confused with the Gateway example in the official document: https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#gateway-example.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: ext-host-gwy
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-gateway-controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - ext-host.example.com
    tls:
      mode: SIMPLE
      credentialName: ext-host-cert
```

In this example, what is `app: my-gateway-controller` under spec/selector? Is there additional configuration/deployment needed for this my-gateway-controller?

I tried searching "my-gateway-controller" in the rest of the document, but didn't find further explanation.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but infrastructure and service mesh, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Its usually istio ingress gateway pod label name which needs to be given in selector, as the external traffic will enter through ingress gateway pod.  unless the name of ingress gateway is changed during istio installation.

Please mention as below in the gateway definition which will route the traffic to application.

```
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
```

Answer (score 0):

Istio can be installed with different options. They have different profiles that can be used for testing, for default scenarios and custom setup. One option is to configure an ingress-controller (but you could also have non and use a different non-istio ingress-controller).

Depending on your setup you can either have no ingress-gateway, the default ingress-gateway or a custom gateway.

The default gateway has a label that's called `istio: ingressgateway`. You can find that in most of the example/getting started docs, e.g. in [how to setup a secure ingress](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/secure-ingress/#configure-a-tls-ingress-gateway-for-a-single-host)

Here the `Gateway` looks like that:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default ingress gateway
[...]
```

The other option would be to setup a second ingress-gateway that might have a different name. You can for example use the `IstioOperator` manifest to configure this.

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    ingressGateways:
    - enabled: true
      name: my-gateway-controller
```

That ingress-gateway pod will get a label of `app: my-gateway-controller`. This label can than be used as it has been in the example you posted. So you can check all ingress-gateway pods you have and choose the label you need.

If you went with the default setup, you probably have the default ingress-gateway and can simple change the selector to `istio: ingressgateway`.

For the beginning I would recommend to stick with the [tasks section](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/) for configuring your setup, because it's uses the default istio setup most people have. If you need more details or something special you can always check the docs pages.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others have mentioned in the answers, the `selector` key looks for labels. In this case, it's looking for an `istio` label to associate the Gateway object with.

The value of this `istio` label for your Gateway definition should match the value of the `istio` label of the current Istio Gateway pod that should be running.

Assuming that you've deployed Istio in a Kubernetes cluster already, the Istio Gateway is stood up via a `Deployment` object. You could find what this `istio` value must be as follows:

#### Step #1: Find out what deployed the Istio Gateway pod.

```bash
kubectl get deployments -n '<namespace where Istio is deployed>'
```

You should see some table output with the deployments for that namespace.

For example:

```
> kubectl get deployment istio-system

NAME            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
istio-gateway   1/1     1            1           24m
istiod          1/1     1            1           24m
jaeger          1/1     1            1           24m
kiali           1/1     1            1           21m
```

In my case, the Deployment is called `istio-gateway`.

#### Step #2: Find what's the value of the `istio` label.

If you run:

```bash
kubectl get deployment -n '<namespace where Istio is deployed>' '<name of your Istio deployment>' -o yaml
```

You should see some output like this:

```yaml
> kubectl get deployment -n istio-system istio-gateway -o yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: istio-gateway
    istio: gateway # <- this is what you want!
  name: istio-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
```